# How can I create a List off of an Entity Framework entity (object)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can I use the Entity Framework Model to allow me to create a list off of an existing table (entity)? If so I just can't figure out how to do that?

So for instance if I have a table in my DB called Order and that has been added to Entity Framework can I use the Entity Framework model to generate a List of Objects?

using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010

```
var orderContext = new OrderEntities();

var order = orderContext.Order;

List<order> ordersList = new List<order>();
```

That would be cool if I could.

Thanks,

S

Comment: Your question is not clear enough for me.  Are you asking to retrieve rows out of the database as entity objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are using System.Linq, you should be able to do the following. Presuming that Order is a ObjectSet.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then use the [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method.

```
IList<Order> orders = orderContext.Order.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

"order" its a variable, you must create List for Type as:

```
List<Order> list = new List<Order>();
```

And then you can:

```
list = _context.Order.ToList();
```

(need using System.Linq)